# Software Center, appears briefly then disappears. New 16.04 installation

Tags: software-center

I've just installed 16.04 and also upgraded my graphics card and hard drive.

When I try and use the Software Center it briefly flashes this

[image]

then disappears after less then 1 second.

How to get the Ubuntu Software Center working?

I tried doing `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` but it didn't help.  The output from it also included the following:[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by doing

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

(I initially tried `sudo-apt autoremove software-center` but it said not found)

What I then found was that I actually had two software centers, my original 'Software Center' that still doesn't work and then a new program 'Ubuntu Software Center' that *does* work.

[image]

Comment: I experienced the same so can concur with the response from @MichaelDurrant

Answer (score 0):

using 64bit, 16.04LTS

I experienced a similar software-center disappearing problem. I launched Software from Apps>Sys Tools>Software, it showed a brief display of Software Center, then it disappeared.

The following steps, a little different, worked for me:

1)removed everything "software-center" via synaptic

2)sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean

3)sudo apt-get install software-center

Comment: Please don't add answers that are essentially just 'Thanks'. While your answer does include the extra command you ran that it is likly to be over  looked and downvoted. Consider [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/990411/edit) your answer to more clearly highlight that an extra step may be needed, or better yet [suggest an edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/914737/edit) to the OP's answer to the same effect. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](https://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Ask Ubuntu way of saying thank you.